# Titles in revision history are bold if (and only if) the title changed

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list

I noticed this behaviour when looking at the revision history of a hot MathOverflow question:

> The question title is in bold **if and only if** the body was changed. This behavior only occurs in the two parsed output views, not in the markdown view.

[image: Revision 3 has bold title and changed body, revision 2 has narrow title and no changed body].

You can also reproduce this in the formatting sandbox. ([With bold title (revision 262)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions?page=7), [With narrow title (revision 8)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions?page=19))

The problem is that the bold font looks like it is a heading (#, ##, ###) from the body and is not so easily distinguished from the body except for spanning both columns

Comment: Doesn’t show on the mobile app

Comment: @DaniilManokhin shows that this is probably a big and not by design.